# In angular getting: ReferenceError: async is not defined

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I'm using angular 6 and RxJS 6 and when I try this example below, I am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: async is not defined
```

[See use example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28CXZ.png)
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Comment: If you post the code you're using, it might help

Answer (score 0):

It depends what value input value you are passing in the object expression.

Input value should be either **`Observable | Promise | null | undefined`** as `async` pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted.